# Get the 15th and 30th day dynamically Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can i dynamically get the 15th and last day of each month based on the date of which it was created? Saying created date was today, I want to get the next 15th and 30th day continuously

I tried using code this but it wont return any value

Controller

```
req = @request.created_at
@mid_month  = req.beginning_of_month + 14
@end_month  = mid_month + 15
```

View

```
<% @mid_month %>
```

Format of req

```
2017-10-24 00:52:00
```

Comment: Can you provide what format `req` is in?

Comment: @colincr  2017-10-24 00:52:00

Comment: I apologize for the re-write, I've updated my answer to better fit your format.

Comment: note you will need to use <%= @mid_month %> in the view, also, use 14.days and 15.days instead of 14 and 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ActiveSupport](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-time) has some nice helpers for the Time class-

```
time  = Time.parse(@request.created_at)
last_day = time.end_of_month.day
@mid_month = time.strftime("%Y-%m-15 %H:%M:%S")
@end_month = time.strftime("%Y-%m-#{last_day} %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: i get an error of no implicit conversion of Date into String at time  = Time.parse(@request.created_at)

Comment: Does Time.parse(@request.created_at.to_s) work better?

Comment: Last question how can i get the 15 and 30th of the current month and if it reached the 15th change value to 30th?

Comment: Use something like time.day and write a condition for if the value is greater than 15.

Comment: Ok thanks you very last question @mid_month = time.strftime("%Y-%m-15 %H:%M:%S") how do you convert to in this format I am having error long: "%B %d, %Y %H:%M"

Comment: Use Date instead of Time